# how to get proper portrait video in Chrome for Android

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-chrome, html5-video

I'm trying to have video from the front camera of my Nexus 4 displayed properly regardless of the phone's orientation. In landscape mode everything is fine, but in portrait mode I get a vertically letterboxed image which still has landscape instead of portrait proportions, see screenshot at http://i41.tinypic.com/28jdt10.png

I'm using Chrome 28 and 29 (beta) on Android 4.3. For example code see below and http://jsfiddle.net/W4par/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;
    video = document.querySelector('video');
    if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
        navigator.getUserMedia({audio: false, video: true}, function(stream) {
            video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks you were seeing this bug: https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=1977

The ticket says a fix will show up in Chrome M33.

Comment: I can confirm that the issue is fixed in Chrome Beta for Android.